# My env variable in react app is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am using the below `mainEventsURL` as a string which gets fetched by axios. However the hard coded API function works when I fetch it with axios but when I try the dynamic function which uses `process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY` it fails to fetch the data. The `process.env` says its undefined and I can't figure out why.

```
// Dynamic function which returns a string

const main_events = () => `events/search/api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`;
export const mainEventsURL = () => `${base_url}${main_events}`;

// Hard coded string which returns a string

export const mainEventsURL = () =>`https://www.example.com/api/v1/events/search/?api_key=5049045495849405453`;
```

Comment: Did you made an `.env` file in the root of your project?

Comment: yes it is REACT_APP_API_KEY=5888598953783793. Cant figure out why its not getting it

Comment: did you load your api key into the app? See [including env var in react app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#usage)

Comment: Did you use CRA to setup your react project?

Comment: Yes I used CRA so no need to install dotenv package but still getting undefined

Comment: Can you help us reproduce this issue in https://codesandbox.io ?